# Can't send element id data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send id data through ajax, but I always get  undefined variable error. 
  ajax works fine with forms data, but when I try to get the id value this problem occurs.

PHP/ html code

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <?php
        $get_cats = retrieve_cat();
        while($cat_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cats)){

            $id   = $cat_rows['category_id'];
            $title = $cat_rows['category_name'];
            echo "<li><a herf='post_category.php' class='abc' data-id='$id' id='$id' data-target='post_category'> $title </a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(".abc").click(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");        
   edit_data(id);

  function edit_data(id)
  {
    $.ajax({
        url:"post_category.php",
         method:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

And the **post_category.php** page just to echo the value to test it :

```
echo $_POST['id'];
```

The problem  I get this error as I said :

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **C:\xampp\htdocs\unv\post_category.php** on line **6**

But in success function I get the correct value.  I don't know where's the problem!.

This's a picture for more explanation

http://store2.up-00.com/2016-05/1464026786681.png

Comment: Can you please replace `method:"POStT"` to `method:"POST"` ?

Comment: it was an editing mistake, sorry for that.  The POST name is written correctly, but same problem still persists !

Comment: hi, I think the problem is related with the dataType argument, maybe you should pass 'json' instead of 'text', is seems to be a problem related with the type of your request payload... I have no sure how php handle payloads in json form, OR you also can pass 'text', but use JSON.stringify({id: id}) to transform your hash object in text

Comment: Thanks, I tried JSON before and it didn't solve the issue,  ajax works with forms data, but when I try to get the id as I did, this error occurs

Comment: can you put an alert(id) before making ajax call and check the id value

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo. I have rewritten some parts of the code. You can try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.abc', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        edit_data(id);
        function edit_data(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"post_category.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but  it didn't fix it.   http://store2.up-00.com/2016-05/1464026786681.png

Comment: @AhmadzIssa sorry, I missed a line there. Have updated the code. Check the answer

Comment: I called the function in your previous code, and it didn't solve the problem. ajax work fine with forms, but when I try to get the id value as I did  this problem occurs and I have no way to solve it!.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Everything seems fine with code.. BTW let me test it on my server

Comment: It is working for me.. Seems like value isn't being generated at PHP's end. You need to check the `$id` variable to confirm that it really isn't empty

Comment: can I have the code that you used to get the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're including `post_category.php` in your page so it'll try to echo the `id` when it's not there because id will be available just after the click so you have to add a span instead of including the `post_category.php` page :

```
<span id="my-id-here"></span>
```

Then append `id` to it on success callback :

```
....
success:function(data){
    $('#my-id-here').append(data);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to check if it is set or not, when I set it nothing appear, because there's no value passed to the variable!.

Comment: Yes that true because the value will be sent after the click and will not appear in the page but just in the alert box, if you want it to appear in the page you should add a span for example with an id then append it, check my example.

Comment: Yeah it's as you said I tried and it worked and send the data to database. but I want to assign the coming value to a variable  is that possible without getting this error ?

Comment: No, since when you click on the button the page is already sent by the server and the php code is already compiled.

Answer (score 0):

your issues is  `method:"POStT"` change this with below given code.

```
 method:"POST"
```

here is typo mistake in method. actually method name is post.

Comment: I was editing mistake, when I was writing the peoblem here.  it's written POST  in the code correctly thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change

```
method:"POST",
```

To

```
type: "POST",
```

For more information check this [Link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)